# Object Deserialization- to get back int array from serialized Object

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, object-serialization

```
int[] myIntArray;
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new DeflaterOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream));
objectOutputStream.writeObject(myIntArray);
```

Now,`ObjectOutputStream` takes The object and directly serializes it. `DeflaterOutputStream` compresses the serialized result, then the compressed result is stored in a `ByteArrayOutputStream`

Can Someone tell me How to Deserialize and get back my original int array back?
Plz Share the coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
objectOutputStream.close();
byte[] serialized = byteArrayOutputStream.getBytes();

// and then read back using symmetric constructs as when writing, but using 
// input streams instead of output streams:

ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(serialized);
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = 
    new ObjectInputStream(new InflaterInputStream(byteArrayInputStream));
int[] myDesererializedIntArray = (int[]) objectInputStream.readObject();
```

Comment: You probably need to close or finish the stream before transforming to bytes. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: check my complete code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321507/java-deserialization-error-invalid-stream-header

Comment: OK. I finally found the problem. You must use an InflaterInputSTream and not a DeflaterInputStream. Sorry for not having tested my solution sooner. I have now tested it successfully.